# Failing to Create Table

Tags: oracle, ddl, sqldatatypes

I'm new to SQL and I want to create a table. Sometimes I create a table successfully and sometimes I fail. Help me I can't find where I get it wrong when I fail. I always get this error message

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057

3.             (
4.              CustomerID INT(2)
5.             ,CityID INT(2)
6.             ,CustomerName VARCHAR2(20)
7.             ,CONSTRAINT cu_pk PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
```

My SQL statement is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE
        Customer
            (
             CustomerID INT(2)
            ,CityID INT(2)
            ,CustomerName VARCHAR2(20)
            ,CONSTRAINT cu_pk PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is different from MySQL(there is no data type `INT(n)`):

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
         CustomerID INT --remove (2)  or change to NUMBER(2,0)
        ,CityID INT     --(2)
        ,CustomerName VARCHAR2(20)
        ,CONSTRAINT cu_pk PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04e6f862d57bdb33d777aa184da607f0)**

> [11.1.6 Numeric Type Attributes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)
>
> MySQL supports **an extension** for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type.

Comment: @lgTakunda Glad I could help. Btw [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

- `INT` or `INTEGER` in oracle is nothing but the sub type of the `NUMBER` data type.
- `INT/INTEGER` can only accept whole numbers i.e. 1,5,13 etc.
- Oracle supports `INT` as **ANSI** standard have it. But in oracle primary data type for numbers is `NUMBER`.
- `INT/INTEGER` can be represented as following:

  ```
  NUMBER(*,0)
  ```

Here, * means maximum allowed.

> According to [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes002.htm), `INTEGER` is A whole number in
>   the range of (-2^31) to (2^31)-1.

You should use `INT` as data type without any precision. So remove `(2)` after `INT` in your example and you are good to go. If you want only two digit of number then use NUMBER data type as follows:

```
NUMBER(2,0)
```

Cheers!!